# UIAlertView Delegate Protocol in iOS

Tags: ios, uialertview, uialertviewdelegate

I am a beginner in iOS development, and yesterday I learned about the  `UIAlertViewDelegate` protocol from the [Apple developer website](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIAlertViewDelegate_Protocol/UIAlertViewDelegate/UIAlertViewDelegate.html).

I used `-(void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex` for managing the `buttonindex` and the performing the specific task.

However, when I use 2 `UIAlertView`s on the same outlet, they both use the same `UIAlertViewDelegate` protocol. How can I use different delegates for the other `UIAlertView` in my application?

Also, how can I change the default design of the `UIAlertView` in my Application?

Answer (score 4):

Your UIAlertView has a property called tag. After you instantiate your alert view, set its tag:

```
myAlertView.tag = 1;
```

Use a different tag value for each of your alert views.

In your call back method, check the tag first to determine which alert view was dismissed and handle accordingly:

```
if (alertView.tag == 1) {
    //alert view 1 was dimissed, handle that
} else if (alertView.tag == 2) {
    //alert view 2 was dismissed
}
```